Angular routing: selective change of named outlets or don't reload submodule
I have the following routing configuration. It works as expected, but I don't want to reload Module2 ListComponent on every routing event. If the user clicks on a list item on ListComponent it shouldn't reload the list itself.
For example if I'm on module2/route1 and I navigate to module2/route2 I'd like only the details outlet to be updated and not the list.
My first thought was to change <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet> to <app-list-component></app-list-component> but this way the list component is reloaded all the time, the same as it was handled by the router. I assume this is because the app-routing reloads the whole thing again. How can I avoid this?
app.component.html
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

app-routing.module.ts
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module1/module1.module').then(
        (m) => m.Module1Module
      ),
  },
  {
    path: 'module2',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./module2/module2.module').then(
        (m) => m.Module2Module
      ),
  },

module2.component.html
  <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="details"></router-outlet>

module2-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `route1`,
    component: Module2Component,
    children:
    [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'list',
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'details',
        component: Main1Component
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: `route2`,
    component: Module2Component,
    children:
    [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'list',
        component: ListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'details',
        component: Main2Component
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: Module2Component,
    children:
    [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'list',
        component: ListComponent,
      }
    ],
  },


Please use this style of routing, where we have a empty string parent, which contains the list component, then we will re-render, the child routes which only refresh and list component does not refresh!
Routing
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Module2Component } from './module2/module2.component';
import { Main2Component } from './main2/main2.component';
import { Main1Component } from './main1/main1.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ``,
    component: Module2Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'route1',
        component: Main1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'route2',
        component: Main2Component,
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class Module2RoutingModule {}

Module2 component
<app-list />
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Stackblitz Demo

you have already duplicated component for different routes,
i would suggest that you have a single list component registered and use details component as a child component for the list or as children for the list component ex:
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `list`,
    component: ListComponent,
    children:
    [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'details',
        component: Main1Component,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'details2',
        component: Main2Component,
      }
    ],
  }]

